# How can I make CAPS LOCK act like the caps lock key on a mac?

Tags: mac, capslock

For those of you who don't know, the ways the CAPS key on mac works as follows: when you activate the CAPS key, it sends a continuous pulse. On linux (and windows), it only sends one pulse to turn it on and one pulse to turn it off. How can I make my CAPS key work like a mac?

Comment: I found this thread helpful in solving this issue. [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093236/where-is-keyboard-layout-options-on-ubuntu-18-10?newreg=bc66a40299a54e99b38c8b31f5ec0ed4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093236/where-is-keyboard-layout-options-on-ubuntu-18-10?newreg=bc66a40299a54e99b38c8b31f5ec0ed4)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in your **Ubuntu Desktop Guide**.

Click your name on the top bar and select **System Settings**.

Open **Keyboard Layout** and select the Layouts tab.

Click the **Layouts** button, select **Options**, and find the setting you want to adjust.

While you're in **Settings**, click **Language Support**.

You may be prompted to add some language files do this.

**Layouts** allows you to set up full keyboards of "tweak" your current ones.

Comment: Thanks! But which setting will accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Look at: Layout >Options >Caps Lock Key Behavior > Caps Lock Acting as Shift