# Where is 'Keyboard layout options' on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: keyboard-layout, 18.10

I could find this window in Linux Mint and old version of Ubuntu.
But can't find it on Ubuntu 18.10

I want to change keyboard setting such as 
'Alt/Win key behavior'
'Adding Esperanto supersigned letters'

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try search in Applications: **Gnome Tweaks**. Go to tab **Keyboard & Mouse** then **Additional Layout Options** button.

If no Tweaks in installed applications:
Go to **Ubuntu Software** app, search "Gnome Tweaks" and install it.
Or if you prefer console way, run this command in command-line: `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`.