# Caps lock not working properly

Tags: capslock

I'm an AZERTY user, so to type numbers without using the num pad we need to use Caps lock/shift and the same thing for a lot of other special characters.
So I realized that on Ubuntu, <kbd>caps lock</kbd> is only used to capitalize letters. As I got used to using caps lock instead of shift, this became my number 1 issue while switching from windows to Ubuntu, anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to Keyboard options.
- Select your layout then **keyboard layouts options** -> **Caps Lock behavior** -> then select **Caps Lock Toggles ShiftLock** instead of default.

Comment: Can you provide a clearer explanation? I can't seem to find the "Caps Lock behavior" Option.

Comment: @Adya You need to go to Gnome Tweaks, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093236/where-is-keyboard-layout-options-on-ubuntu-18-10